# How do I use pandas to add a column to a csv using a list?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, list

If I want to take a list with m number of elements and add it as the very first column to an existing csv file with m number of rows, what would be the easiest way to do that using pandas?

Comment: Are you asking about: 1) reading the CSV, 2) creating a new column, 3) ordering columns, or 4) writing the CSV? Those are your basic steps and all are covered in the docs and many questions already on Stack Overflow

Answer (score 0):

use `pd.insert` to add your data from first column (if you have a simple list/column of values), I think it's very simple to use, just pass as first parameter the index where you wull insert these values for example:

```py
import pandas as pd

# load your data from file or use this following example
# df = pd.read_csv ('data.csv')

df = pd.DataFrame({'key': ['K0', 'K1', 'K2', 'K3', 'K4', 'K5'],
'A': ['A0', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5']})

values=[1,2,3,4,5,6]

df.insert(0, column='new', value=values)
```

output:

| index | new | key | A |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | K0 | A0 |
| 1 | 2 | K1 | A1 |
| 2 | 3 | K2 | A2 |
| 3 | 4 | K3 | A3 |
| 4 | 5 | K4 | A4 |
| 5 | 6 | K5 | A5 |

Answer (score -1):

You can copy the csv to a df then re-add the data back into the csv

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(file_path)
df['New_Column'] = 'Whatever'
df[['New_Column', 'Another_Column', 'Yet_Another_Column']].to_csv(file_path)
```

Comment: Thank you! Now, with the new csv file I get, the first column is numbered 1 to m going down, any idea on how to get rid of this?

Comment: @Benji that is the index of the dataframe. `.to_csv` has options for this.